# Complex filtering queries with multiple attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a page where I am listing some entities and providing an interface with multiple filtering options. For simplifying the question, Let's say I am listing various movies on that page. So de-normalized row should look like this for a single movie entry;

- `producer_id`: Partition Key - (e.g: PRODUCER#213141)
- `movie_id`: Sort Key - (e.g: MOVIE#887347)
- `producer_name`: (e.g: "Warner Bros")
- `movie_name`: (e.g: "Harry Potter")
- `status`: (e.g: "ON_SHOW")
- `publish_date`: (e.g: "2020.01.01")
- `type`: (e.g: "fantasy")
- `language`:(e.g: "English")

I want to enable filtering by using a composite attribute used as a GSI secondary key. My composite attribute would look like something like this;

- `GS1SK`: "harry_potter#2020.01.01#fantasy#English#ON_SHOW"

And the partition key for this secondary index would be simply the `producer_id`.

So let's say any user comes to the page and wants to filter out the movies with the given filtering options. Such an access pattern example would be;

> Get all of the **sci-fi** movies produced by **Warner Bros** and has
> the status **ON_SHOW**.

However, the problem starts here. Since the combined attributes are not hierarchical, the composite attribute can't be used for this scenario. Because in the above access pattern example, the user had the option to not specify any date, simply wanted to get results for any date range. But when you look at the structure of the composite attribute, it is impossible to not specify the date range for filter other attributes in advance such as movie type or movie language.

I know the DynamoDB is not the best fit for such complex querying, however, I think providing filtering options in a listing page is a really typical scenario that even the simplest products should provide. My question is, what kind of approach should I use to satisfy this filtering needs.

1. Maybe I am getting the idea wrong behind composite attributes?
2. Should I use filtering expressions and there is no way to do such advanced filtering with composite GSIs?
3. Maybe for such scenarios, I should be considering Elastic Search or AWS Athena services?
4. I will need to provide even more filtering options in the other pages of my application, such as filtering listed users with their demographic information. Do you think I should be considering migrating RDBS rather than using a NO-SQL database?

What I really want to do is to provide these filtering features without any filtering expressions to reduce RCU usage, and increase the efficiency in my queries. I would appreciate any kind of help and advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you understand composite attributes perfectly and have a solid grasp of your options.  You've stumbled across one of the weaknesses of DynamoDB.  It's challenging to support this kind of ad-hoc search functionality with DynamoDB.

I've seen this problem solved using a tool like Elastic Search (your option #3).  A common pattern is to enable DynamoDB streams, which can be used to update the Elastic Search index.  A bit more infrastructure to set up, but the search capabilities would be much more flexible than what you get with DynamoDB alone.